# CasperJS and automating export xml from mediawiki

Tags: phantomjs, mediawiki, casperjs

I am trying to automate the export of the media wiki xml using casperjs as we have no access via the machine hosting it. The problem is the downloading of the xml as its a post request which the response is the xml. Currently I have the following (Another ticket has on stack overflow brought be this code)

```
    casper.then(function(){
       var theFormRequest = this.page.evaluate(function() {
          var request = {}; 
          var formDom = document.forms[0];
          formDom.onsubmit = function() {
              //iterate the form fields
              var data = {};
              for(var i = 0; i < formDom.elements.length; i++) {
              data[formDom.elements[i].name] = formDom.elements[i].value;
            }
            request.action = formDom.action;
            request.data = data;
            return false; //Stop form submission
        }

        var link = $(".visualClear").submit();      
        return request; 
    }); 


        this.echo("DOWNLOADING  " + theFormRequest.action + "  " + theFormRequest.data);
        casper.download(theFormRequest.action, "downloaded_file.xml", "POST", theFormRequest.data);
    });
```

I have used resource.received event but this just gives me the meta data of the response not the actual data. Currently what gets downloaded is the html page and not the xml, i can confirm that the button is being clicked as if I remove the formDom.onSubmit the resource.received shows that the content.type coming back is XML.

Although its different in terms of classes used from my mediawiki, here is the mediawiki page doing the exact same thing https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:Export

Thanks

Edit
Here is the response when done through browser

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Age:0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-disposition:attachment;filename=file-20161010165904.xml
Content-Length:172717
Content-Type:application/xml; charset=utf-8
Date:Mon, 10 Oct 2016 16:59:04 GMT
Server:nginx
Via:1.1 varnish
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Powered-By:HHVM/3.15.1
X-Varnish:1482412076
```

Comment: I'm not sure about the answer to your question, but if you're trying to pull a complete download of a wiki you might be interested in the Wikiteam archiving tools: https://github.com/WikiTeam/wikiteam

Answer (score 0):

What I would do :

```
casper.start();

casper.open('http://url_to_mediawiki', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/xml; charset=utf-8',
        },
        encoding: 'utf8'
    }
})

casper.then(function() {
    this.echo(this.getPageContent());
})
```

`getPageContent()` is content agnostic, it's flexible. It just render what it find. Check [casper#getpagecontent](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#getpagecontent) and [casper#open](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#open)